# Attacks for toothy half-orc bear shaman druid

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat, natural-weapon

Taking the half-orc alternate racial feature Toothy grants me 1d3 primary natural bite attack.

At level 2 a bear shaman can take a totem transformation granting the character a 1d6 bite attack and two 1d4 claw attacks.

Would I replace the bite from toothy half-orc with the totem transformation, or would I get to use both bite attacks? (For four total natural attacks)